# Style Inputted Text in Input CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like the text that the user inputs to follow these rules:

```css
 .emailInput {
        padding-left: 5px;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<div class="loginBox">
  <form class="loginForm">
    <h1 class="loginLabel">Login</h1>
    <div class="underline"></div>
    <input class="emailInput" placeholder="Email">
    <input class="passwordInput" placeholder="Password">
    <a href="" title="Button border lightblue" class="loginButton button btnFloat btnLightBlue"></a>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
::-webkit-input-text {
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: the selector should be `input[type='text']`

Comment: And the problem you're having, other than not having any elements with the `inputText` class, is...?

Comment: It seems to work fine as is?

Comment: @Scath The text `color` is white ;)

Comment: @cyberpirate yea you just highlight it and you can see it is taking the padding. I don't know why it is white but that's how he has it.

Comment: @Michael It's working perfectly fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/wfhaq0d4/

Answer (score 0):

i think your html is missing the type of the input .
they sould looks like this

```
<input type="text" class="emailInput" placeholder="Email">
<input type="password" class="passwordInput" placeholder="Password">
```

and your css should works fine .

```
.emailInput {
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: white;
}
```

or

```
input {
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: this pads the entire element, i only want the text inside of the box to be padded

Comment: @Michael I'm not clear on the difference. Can you help clarify?